# Как сделать анимацию

Tags: android, activity, android-animation

Постараюсь на словах объяснить суть вопроса. Хочу сделать переход между активити со списком (например, контактов) к активити с информацией о контакте по типу как в мобильном Google play перелетает иконка приложения при подобном переходе на активити с подробной информацией о приложении.  Подскажите, куда копать, откуда начать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Копайте в сторону shared element transitions. Вот [пример реализации](http://guides.codepath.com/android/shared-element-activity-transition)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);

//помещаем в intent данные (в ваше случае это будут данные о контакте)
intent.putExtra(DetailsActivity.EXTRA_CONTACT, contact);

ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
//ivProfile - ссылка на картинку, которая будет "перелетать" между экранами
//в layout файле у этого imageView обязательно нужно указать transitionName, 
//например profile
makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, (View)ivProfile, "profile");
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: добавил пример кода